# Slider handle needs to restricted inside the container, should not go beyond the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

In the custom slider i have created, the handle is moving beyond the container. But i want it to stay within the container limits. We could just do it simple by setting margin-left as offset in CSS. But My requirement is when the handle right end detect the container's end the handle should not be allowed to move anymore. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Demo Link: https://jsfiddle.net/mohanravi/1pbzdyyd/30/

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('contain')[0].addEventListener("mousedown", downHandle);

function downHandle() {
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveHandle);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", upHandle);
}

function moveHandle(e) {
  var left = e.clientX - document.getElementsByClassName('contain')[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var num = document.getElementsByClassName('contain')[0].offsetWidth / 100;
  var val = (left / num);

  if (val < 0) {
    val = 0;
  } else if (val > 100) {
    val = 100;
  }

  var pos = document.getElementsByClassName('contain')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width * (val / 100);

  document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.left = pos + 'px';
}

function upHandle() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveHandle);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", upHandle);
}
```

```css
.contain {
  height: 4px;
  width: 450px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 40px;
}

.bar {
  width: 90px;
  height: 12px;
  background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 7px);
  left: 0px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class='contain'>
  <div class='bar'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to select a single element, use querySelector, that's what it's for - it's not great to use a method that returns a collection (such as getElementsByClassName) and then select the first element in the collection.

Comment: see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1pbzdyyd/40/) updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 
this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.left = pos + 'px';
```

to this

```
if(pos > 90){
  document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.left = pos - 90 + 'px';
  }
  else{
  document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0].style.left = 0 + 'px';
  }
```

since width of your bar is 90px I am subtracting 90.

See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pbzdyyd/40/)

Comment: You also need to count in `2px` because of the left & right border, or use `.bar {box-sizing: border-box}`.

Comment: @VXp yes. sorry did not notice that. but box-sizing can be used